# Need help with an integral problem. Don't understand the solution.

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem:** Prove that the volume of a pyramid is $$\frac{1}{3}Bh$$ where B is the area of the base and h is the height of the pyramid.

**Solution:** Define the x-axis to pass through the vertex of the pyramid (which is set as the origin) and be parallel to the height of the pyramid. Consider a disk of infinitesimal thickness $dx$, whose parallel surfaces are perpendicular to the x-axis and are at x-coordinates $x$ and $x + dx$. The two surfaces of the disk have areas $A$ and $A + dA$ respectively and the total volume of this element is
$$(1 + A +A+dA) dx= Adx$$
Due to the similarity between the entire pyramid and the pyramid from the top up to a distance x from the vertex,
$$\frac{A}{B}= \frac{x^2}{h^2}$$
The volume is obtained by integrating x from 0 to the height of the pyramid h:
$$V = \int_{h}^{0} A dx =  \int_{h}^{0}  \frac{x^2}{h^2} Bdx = (1/3) B h$$.

So my first problem with this is I can't picture it in my head. What is the orientation of the pyramid? Is it upsidedown to place the vertex at the origin?

Secondly, I don't understand how they got the relationship $$\frac{A}{B}= \frac{x^2}{h^2}$$.

Can anyone please explain? I'm self-studying out of passion and have nobody to help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to imagine that the pyramid is, indeed, upside-down, with the vertex at the origin and the base sitting on the plane $x = h$.

If you then consider the section of the pyramid you get by slicing the top of it off at some height $x$, it will be similar to the full pyramid, meaning that all of the lengths will be scaled by some constant factor $r$, all of the areas by $r^2$, and all of the volumes by $r^3$ relative to the full pyramid. Since the height of the smaller pyramid is $x$ we easily get $r = \frac{x}{h}$, and so the area of its base is $A = r^2 B = \frac{x^2}{h^2} B$ which gets you the needed relation.

Comment: Oh I see. They skipped those steps which got me confused. Thank you so much for the help:)

Answer (score 1):

Yeach.  That's poorly written.  Let's go back to the drawing board.

---

Define $x$ as *a height measured from the apex of the pyramid down a plumb-line (perpendicular to the base)*, and $A(x)$ as the cross-sectional area at that height.

By similarity of shapes, the cross sectional area at any height is proportional to square of this height, and since $A(h)=B$ (being the base area), we thus have:

$$A(x)=  (x/h)^2 B$$

Evaluating the volume by integration of cross sectional area with respect to height gives:$$\begin{align}V&=\int_0^h A(x)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\dfrac B{h^2}\int_0^h x^2\,\mathrm d x\\&=\dfrac {Bh} 3\end{align}$$